# Set Configure Kubernetes scheduler interval?

Tags: kubernetes

I use k8s to run large compute Jobs (to completion). There are not many jobs nor nodes in my setup so scale is small.

I noticed that the scheduler do not start a pod immediately when a node is available. It takes between 5 to 40 seconds for a pod to be scheduled once node is ready.

Is there a way to make the scheduler more "aggressive"? I cant find a setting for the interval in Default Scheduler custom policy. Is implementing my own scheduler the only way forward? Any tips appreciated!

Comment: May I know how do you get this metric that describes: time taken [in sec] for a pod to be scheduled once node is ready ?

Comment: Job resource request are set so that only one pod (with one container) is run at a node at a time. Let's say every node has a running container for a pod/job. I'm querying the API with kubectl. When a job is marked as complete, I'm continuing to poll until a pending jobs pods container is marked as "container creating".

Answer (score 1):

There is difference between pod scheduling and pod creation.  Scheduler only find suitable node and schedule pod to that node but pod creation  done by kubelet.

Kubelet polls api-server for desired state and get newly scheduled pod spec and then create pod.

So this process can take time you Specfied in question.

So i dont think writing custom scheduler  help here.

Comment: Thank you! 

Do you know if it's possible to make some of the steps in this process faster?